# nginx configure error pages

Tags: 404, nginx, configuration

Mostly that I need to be more familiar with the configuration of nginx and I have tried to search for an answer but have been unable to find one,I need to have all 401 403 and 404 errors directed to `/error.php`, however, my configuration seems to serve `/` instead. If you want to try this working have a look, it is on the PHP mirror at http://php.willtech.net.au/

The problem is noticeable when the page generates a link such as,
https://php.willtech.net.au/manual/en/function.random-bytes
However, the page that needs to be served is,
https://php.willtech.net.au/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php
Which works and I expect `/error.php` to resolve that automatically albeit the nginx configuration could do it I would suppose there will be other parts of the PHP mirror that also rely on the `/error.php`

I could make some presumptions but then I would not be so certain that there was not any other problem, it is a better opportunity to learn from somebody more experienced.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    port_in_redirect off;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/www-access-site.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/www-error-site.log;

    root  /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_page 401 403 404 /error.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param MIRROR_LANGUAGE "en";
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about nginx, but isn't `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` going to fall back to `index.php` if `$uri` doesn't exist?  Why is `/index.php?$query_string` in that list?

Comment: Changing `/index.php?$query_string` to `/error.php` resolves the example, appreciated. In the case of https://php.willtech.net.au/manual/ performance is different to https://php.net/manual/

Comment: Why did you change it to `/error.php` as opposed to removing it?  Why was it there in the first place?   Where did your nginx configuration come from anyway?  If you are mirroring for some other site, presumably you would want to use the same configuration they use.

Comment: Routing everything to `error.php` would seem to be an "error" (no pun intended), when you are seemingly trying to serve extensionless URLs. (?) I notice your example URL now results in an external redirect to append `.php` (which is incorrect) and there is an erroneous intermediary redirect from HTTPS to HTTP and back to HTTPS. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you for taking a look. In comparison with php.net it is a mirror site by rsync from the instructions https://php.willtech.net.au/mirroring.php - If I look carefully possibly the http/https redirects are provided by Cloudflare insisting on https possibly I suppose I could turn off... The .php extension request tends to generate links to additional pages including the .php extension but, short links do use `error.php` in the example `https://php.willtech.net.au/mirroring-troubles.php` `https://php.willtech.net.au/echo` `https://php.willtech.net.au/manual/en/function.echo.php`

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be resolved with the following configuration, accepting your comments for improvement.

```
server {
server_name php.willtech.net.au;
    listen 80;
    port_in_redirect off;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/www-access-site.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/www-error-site.log;

    root  /var/www/html;
    index index.php;
    error_page 401 403 404 /error.php?$query_string;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /error.php?$query_string;
    }
    
    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param MIRROR_LANGUAGE "en";
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```